# Customise EKEventController Style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ekeventkit

Is is it possible to customise an EKEventViewController to look how you wish, so background colour or image, cells style and all the rest, or will it require a custom view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in API for this. However, you could probably use some public apis to change this, example:

```
for (UIView *subView in ekViewController.view.subviews)
{
     if (subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString("CellClassHere"))
     {
         // example
         subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     }
}
```